# Compile Error: Field expression not allowed for generic SObject at line 26 column 67

Tags: trigger

```
public class contactTriggerHandler {
    Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    public void performOnAfterInsert(List<Contact> lstCon){

        for (contact con : lstCon ) {        
            if(con.AccountId != null){
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);

                List<Account> AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
                List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

                for (AggregateResult ar: cont){
                    Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
                    AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
                }
                update AcctToUpdate;
            }
        } 
    }


    public void performOnAfterUpdate(List<contact> lstcon) {

        for (contact con : lstcon) {
            if(con.AccountId==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != null){
                AccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
            }


            if(con.AccountId!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != null && con.AccountId != Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId) {
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
                AccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
            }

            if(con.AccountId!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId == null){
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
            }

            List<Account> AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
            List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

            for(AggregateResult ar: cont){
                Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
                AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
            }
            update AcctToUpdate;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs more detail.  It's great you included a code sample with an error, but you should add what you've tried, what you're attempting to do, or really just a sentence saying "I hit this error and need some help, does anyone understand the reason for this error?"

Answer (score 2):

Outside of a trigger (e.g. in a handler class like yours) the expression:

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id)
```

evaluates to the generic type SObject which has methods that allow access but does not have the SObject-type specific fields available. The normal solution to this is to pass `Trigger.oldMap` from the trigger where it evaluates to the correct SObject type (I assume Contact in your case) into the class:

```
public void performOnAfterUpdate(List<contact> lstcon, Map<Id, Contact> oldMapCon) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you could use the generic methods like [get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2) or cast to type `Contact`.

Answer (score 1):

Here problem is in your `Trigger.oldMap` which is generic for all the object and compiler is not able to identify the object in `Trigger.oldMap`.

so for that you need to explicitly type cast that at **line no. 26 like** :

```
AccountIds.add(((Map<Id, Contact>)Trigger.oldMap).get(con.Id).AccountId);
```