# when update particular contact accountid count will not increase or decrease performOnAfterUpdate method not working

Tags: trigger, community, controller

below this is my trigger

```
trigger countRecord on Contact (After insert, After update) {
    contactTriggerHandler handler = new contactTriggerHandler();

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        handler.performOnAfterInsert(Trigger.New);
    }

    else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        handler.performOnAfterUpdate(Trigger.Old,trigger.oldmap);
    }
}
```

below this is my handler class for trigger

```
public class contactTriggerHandler {
    Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    public void performOnAfterInsert(List<Contact> lstCon){

        for (contact con : lstCon ) {        
            if(con.AccountId != null){
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);

                List<Account> AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
                List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

                for (AggregateResult ar: cont){
                        Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
                        AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
                }
                update AcctToUpdate;
            }
         } 
    }


    public void performOnAfterUpdate(List<contact> lstcon, Map<Id, Contact> oldMapCon) {

        for (contact con : lstcon) {
                  if(con.AccountId==null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null){
                        //AccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                        AccountIds.add(((Map<Id, Contact>)Trigger.oldMap).get(con.Id).AccountId);
                  }


                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null && con.AccountId != oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId){
                       AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
                        AccountIds.add(oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                   }


                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId == null){
                        AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
                  }

        List<Account> AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

        for(AggregateResult ar: cont){
            Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
            AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
            update AcctToUpdate;
     } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your prev question solved.. you should accept the best ans and close that question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104612/compile-error-field-expression-not-allowed-for-generic-sobject-at-line-26-colum

Comment: I don't find any custom field in the code. Which field you are updating ?

Comment: Prabhat Kumar i have updating My_Contact__c field its i have created in Account Object.when particular record inserted in contact , accountid count increase by one but when we update accounid count will not effect performOnAfterUpdate method not working in my contactTriggerHandler class

Comment: Ratan my issue not solved performOnAfterUpdate method not woking

Comment: I have a custom field on Account called "My_Contact__c" (api name). I'm trying to write an apex trigger on contact that when the field is updated/inserted and it has an account name linked or unlinked to it, it updated on Account "My_Contact__c" by an increment of 1 or a decrement of 1. I tried to implement and my code paste it earlier and i use handlerclass thats name is contactTriggerHandler and in this two methods i have created first one is performOnAfterInsert is working but second method performOnAfterUpdate not working.whats wrong in performOnAfterUpdate method kindly update my code

Comment: i have changed if(con.AccountId==null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null) into if(**con.AccountId!=null** && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null)
and its working but when i have not save particular accountID than what will happed

Comment: @ratan suppose when my saved record update and now i change account id into null than my counting will decrease by 1 of particualr account name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class contactTriggerHandler {
   public Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
   public List<Account> AcctToUpdate;
    public void performOnAfterInsert(List<Contact> lstCon){

        for (contact con : lstCon ) {  

            if(con.AccountId != null){
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);

               AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
                List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

                for (AggregateResult ar: cont){
                        Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
                        AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
                }

            }
         }
                update AcctToUpdate;
                system.debug('insertworking'); 
    }


    public void performOnAfterUpdate(List<contact> lstcon, Map<Id, Contact> oldMapCon) {
    system.debug('!!enter');
        for (contact con : lstcon) {
                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null){
                        AccountIds.add(oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                        system.debug('@1-'+oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                  }


                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null && con.AccountId != oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId){
                       AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
                       system.debug('@2-'+con.AccountId);
                        AccountIds.add(oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                        system.debug('@3-'+oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                   }


                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId == null){
                        AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
                        system.debug('@4-'+con.AccountId);
                  }

        AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

        for(AggregateResult ar: cont){
            Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
            AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
     } 
     update AcctToUpdate;
    }
}
```